Minimal Dependency Injection Preference Example
I am trying to change the logic in my Elasticsearch engine from "and" logic to "or" logic following the advise of the second answer in this question How do I change Magento 2 search from OR logic to AND?.  I have gotten stuck on the di.xml part.  I have implemented the di.xml and the Match.php in a Hello World module that I know works.  Right now, the Match.php file is identical to the original so I would expect if the di.xml file is working correctly that nothing would happen.   Instead, when I try to compile, I end up with the product pages being blank, and this problem goes away if I remove the di.xml file.  I am still new to Magento 2 and haven't created a working di.xml file yet and figured it was time to learn.  I have been searching for a di.xml example that I could use to verify that I have working di.xml file, but most of the examples/solutions had too much extra context to implement and I have not been able to get any of them to work.  I am wondering if anyone could provide a simple as possible example of a working di.xml file that uses preferences to override a class and gives easy to find output such as printing to a test page.

Make sure you put your di.xml file under frontend directory.
etc/frontend/di.xml

di.xml demo file with minimum content:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match"
        type="<VENDOR>\<Module>\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match" />
</config>

This preference will override the default file (in for argument) with your file (in type argument).
If any queries, let me know. We can connect and I will make you understand more.
A simple example of di.xml using preference to change Page title extending Magento\Cms\Block\Page class.
app/code/Tridhyatech/Core/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" type="Tridhyatech\Core\Block\Page" />
</config>


app/code/Tridhyatech/Core/Block/Page.php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Tridhyatech\Core\Block;

use Magento\Cms\Block\Page as CMSPageBlock;

class Page extends CMSPageBlock
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Tridhyatech Title'));
        return $this;
    }
}



Thank you for your answer.  I actually already have the Elasticsearch problem fixed, but I am hoping for a different example that requires less context for the benefit of future readers.  I am wondering if there is a "Hello World" style example of a preference override that would rewrite some basic class and print a message to somewhere easy to find such as a test page or a log.

Hi @Jack, I have edited the answer. Kindly check now and let me know if you still need assistance. Please upvote and accept the answer if you find it helpful.
